# Use string variable as cell reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with Excel macro.
I have cell references written in cells in a workbook.
like:`Sheets("Lam PVB").Cells(21,2)`

Then I construct a path to access cell value in another workbook

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("17.01.2019.xls")
Dim wbMahud As Workbook: Set wbMahud = Workbooks("mahudMakro.xlsm")
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wbMahud.Sheets("jaotus")
    dataStr = wb & "." & ws.Cells(2, 1).Value & ".Value"
    Debug.Print (dataStr)
```

Problem here is that `dataStr` is definitely a string variable and `Debug.Print` outputs same string variable, but I need to get cell value it refers to.

What conversion I'm missing here?

Comment: You cannot convert contents of string to code in VBA

Comment: You cannot do that. What is your actual goal that you want to achieve? I think you asked x but want to achieve y. See [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) • Then [edit] and improve your question.

Comment: You can take a look into [Application.Evaluate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot convert a string into VBA code. But what you can do is using an address.

If you put into your cell in worksheet `jaotus` cell A2: `'Lam PVB'!B21` which references the same cell as `Sheets("Lam PVB").Cells(21,2)`, then you could use:

```
Range(ws.Cells(2, 1).Value).Value
```

to get the range of the address `'Lam PVB'!B21`.